# How to select a specific frame based on timestamp in openCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to edit a specific frame in a video, but I only have the time in milliseconds in which I should make the edit. How to use this information to get the frame? 
 A python example would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

based on this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get), the time related to a given frame can be found in the property **CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC**
where the doc is saying:

```
CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC Current position of the video file in milliseconds or video capture timestamp.
```

---

**Update:**
As mentioned by @Mouldri in the comments below, the value has been changed to `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` in openCV 3.

Comment: Thanks ! This is what I was looking for ! I upvodeted your aswnser

Comment: For Open CV 3, the value has been rename : CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC